# Preferred lambda syntax?

Tags: language-design, grammar

I'm playing around a bit with my own C like DSL grammar and would like some oppinions.

I've reserved the use of "(...)" for invocations. eg:

```
foo(1,2);
```

My grammar supports "trailing closures" , pretty much like Ruby's blocks that can be passed as the last argument of an invocation.

Currently my grammar support trailing closures like this:

```
foo(1,2)
{
   //parameterless closure passed as the last argument to foo
}
```

or

```
foo(1,2) [x]
{
    //closure with one argument (x) passed as the last argument to foo
    print (x);
}
```

The reason why I use [args] instead of (args) is that (args) is ambigious:

```
foo(1,2) (x)
{
}
```

There is no way in this case to tell if foo expects 3 arguments (int,int,closure(x)) or if foo expects 2 arguments and returns a closure with one argument(int,int) -> closure(x)
So thats pretty much the reason why I use [] as for now.

I could change this to something like:

```
foo(1,2) : (x)
{
}
```

or

```
foo(1,2) (x) ->
{
}
```

So the actual question is, what do you think looks best?

[...] is somewhat wrist unfriendly.

```
let x = [a,b] 
{
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: If anyone is interested in this sort of things, here is what I have so far : http://rogeralsing.com/?s=plastic

Comment: Out of interest, why are square brackets `[...]` wrist intensive?  On my keyboard they are lowercase letters next to return, same keys as braces, easier to type than any of the other bracket types.

Comment: On my swedish keyboard they are altgr+8/9, so a bit wrist intensive..

Comment: Almost every language uses parentheses more often than square brackets, so if you're programming on a standard US keyboard, you should have them switched around so that parentheses are unshifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Groovy's syntax, which is

```
foo(1,2) { x ->
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've decided to use this approach , but with ":" as separator as for now... eg foo(1,2) {arg : arg.bar == 2}

Comment: -> or => (C# style) is neat. better than lambda key word from ruby

Answer (score 3):

I don't think bounding to C like syntax is good idea. I hope you checked Haskell syntax. If you're making a DSL, I think it's main purpose is *abstraction* of the domain. Basically, C like syntax is too verbose...

Haskell example:

```
-- Defining a function
add x y = x + y

-- Defining a lambda function ('\' means lambda character 'λ')
add = \ x y -> x + y
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the C# syntax, nice and short
    (x, y) => { /* code */ }

And to declare
    Action< int, int>

Answer (score 2):

I have always thought they should be threated as any other regular parameter.

Consider javascript

```
 sort( sortFunctionGoesHere );
```

Invoked as:

```
sort( function( a, b ) {
    return b - a; 
});
```

So, I would rather have:

```
foo( int, int , closure(int) )
```

And use it like this:

```
foo( 1, 2, (x) {
...    
})
```

Comment: The thing is, if you do this extensively, your code contains a lot of closing braces, that are hard to associate with their counterpart. Also, by convention, a trailing block quite clearly communicates iteration, whereas passing a function object could also be an asynchronous callback or an iteration block (and possibly other things).

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. I have seen this in Smalltalk and Javascript before, and in both, they were part of the parameters. It was until Ruby and the Groovy that I saw the form you mention.  Anyway, interesting  +1

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the closure parameter should be a normal part of the parameter list.

Thus, there is no fundamental difference in declaration or usage. I strongly dislike Ruby introducing special cases with `yield`, non-first-class functions and an `&`-parameter.

Just

```
function foreach(collection, f) 
  // code
end
```

so

```
foreach([1, 2, 3], print)
```

should work in any case.

That said, you can *add* syntactic sugar for providing a final lambda argument in a more convenient way. I see two major options, depending on your language design.

1. Plain syntax sugar. I like @ammoQ's approach with

   ```
   foreach([1, 2, 3]) { x ->
      print(x)
   }
   ```

   So `f(args ...) { vars -> body }` is literally translated to `f(args ..., λvars -> body)`
2. That's the way i.e. Scala does it. As you mentioned

   > There is no way in this case to tell if foo expects 3 arguments (int,int,closure(x)) or if foo expects 2 arguments and returns a closure with one argument(int,int) -> closure(x)

   Just use this idea - a function returning another function to be called is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which is a very common pattern in functional programming.

   If you have curried functions in your language as Scala does, you just need a syntax for closures with `{ }` being equal to regular parentheses. The rest is a regular call semantic. I.e.

   ```
   function foo(a, b)(c)(f) 
   end
   ...
   foo(1, 2)(3) { x -> x + 1 }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, defining the argument within the block is easier, because it resolves a lot of ambiguities, for example the way Groovy does it, as @ammoQ pointed out.

Ruby also does this, but is a little easier to parse than Groovy: `foo(1,2) { |x,y| ... }`

This can be simply parsed from left to right and it is simpler to read. Also, chances are good, you'll never allow `|` as a unary operator (i.e. at the beginning of a statement), so the risk of ambiguity is extremely low.

If that is too "wrist intense", I suppose `foo(1,2) { <x,y> ... }` might help on english keyboards.